# Numba implementation of nested sorting of list/array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, nested-loops, numba

I am trying to use the following function with **Numba**:

```
@numba.njit
def nested_sort(s):
    return sorted(s, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))

s = [[1, 3, 11], [2, 3, 19], [3, 2, 18], [4, 2, 9]] 
nested_sort(s)
```

However, this function is not supported in Numba. I am looking for a variation of this function that will work with Numba in no python mode.

Comment: Numpy has [numpy.sort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):`import numpy as np; np.sort([[1, 3, 11], [2, 3, 19], [3, 2, 18], [4, 2, 9]], order=[1,2])`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html). It sorts based on the *reversed* order of the sequence of keys specified. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392803/sorting-numpy-array-in-the-same-manner-as-sorted-key) might also be relevant.

```py
sorted_s = s[np.lexsort((s[:,2], s[:,1]))]
```

Edit: you seemed to have edited your question, you are no longer looking for a numpy answer. I am still leaving this answer here.

Comment: I may not have been clear. I am looking for Numba implementation in no python mode. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekMamgain good to know. Is there a specific reason for this? Numba is a lot faster than plain Python, but the speedup compared to numpy functions is a lot smaller. Functions like `np.lexsort` are implemented in C or Fortran already. If you compare my solution to your answer, it is a lot faster. I'm not sure you will get much more. Numba is mainly designed for speeding up Python for loops, which you don't have. Unless you code your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: This function is part of a larger code base that runs 10e6 loops to get the results out. To use parallization of np.lexsort, I would need to build a huge array which will eat up all the memory. Therefore I am leaning towards the Numba.

Comment: @AbhishekMamgain makes sense. If memory is your issue, then it is likely that you will have to manually code a sorting algorithm and wrap it in the Numba decorator.

Comment: @AbhishekMamgain Numba cannot run nopython functions on reflected list (ie. CPython lists). This is not possible because Numba developpers explicitly decided not to support them anymore due to they fondamental inefficiency. There are only two solution. The first is to use typed list and the second is to use array. The latter is faster than the former. Note that the conversion needs to be done by the calling function because conversion are slow, especially in a code doing "10e6 loops". Put it shortly, you need to solve the caller function and possibly use Numba for it to reduce the overheads.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write pure python code for nested sort. This works flawlessly with numba.

```
x1 = [i[1] for i in s]
x2 = [i[2] for i in s]

def nested_sort(x1, x2):
    n = len(x1)
    indices = np.arange(n)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if x2[i] > x2[j] or (x2[i] == x2[j] and x1[i] > x1[j]):
                x1[i], x1[j] = x1[j], x1[i]
                x2[i], x2[j] = x2[j], x2[i]
                indices[i], indices[j] = indices[j], indices[i]
    return indices
```